# Drupal 8 : How to write custom php functions and call the function from a custom page?

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am new to Drupal web development.
I have already used Wordpress platform by building a custom plugin to write custom php functions, and calling the function from a custom page was easy.

example:

```
<?php
function givenumber(){
  return 50;
}
?>;
```

Which I call by using:

```
<?php  echo givenumber(); ?>
```

- How can I achieve similar with Drupal 8?
- Do I need to create a custom module for writing the custom php functions?
- How do I call a function from a custom page?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this in Drupal 8 is to create a service in a custom module yes.

Create a module with the following structure:

```
your_custom_module/
├── your_custom_module.info.yml
├── your_custom_module.services.yml
└── src/
    └── YourCustomService.php
```

Your `your_custom_module.services.yml` file:

```
services:
  your.custom.service:
    class: Drupal\your_custom_module\YourCustomService
```

Your Service class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_custom_module;

class YourCustomService {

  public function giveNumber() {
    return 1234;
  }

}
```

Enable the module and you can now call this service:

```
\Drupal::service('your.custom.service')->giveNumber();
```

See more details in [Structure of a service file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/structure-of-a-service-file)

Comment: Thank you for your solution! However, I don't know how to call the service from drupal custom page.

Comment: You can call this from your custom route's controller method with `\Drupal::service('your.custom.service')->giveNumber();`

Comment: Worth to quote drupal.org saying: _Dependency injection is the preferred method for accessing and using services in Drupal 8 and should be used whenever possible. Rather than calling out to the global services container, services are instead passed as arguments to a constructor or injected via setter methods._

Answer (score 0):

There is 'N' number of ways. And, it depends on your use case.

If you want some custom value and just show in your content page. There are `hook_preprocess_node()` functions that you can write in your active theme, and make some variables available to your twig file.